# Tradução de hint ao sinalizar Pergunta

Tags: debate, tradução

Realizando algumas análises de primeira publicação me deparei com o seguinte caso:

 Demorei um pouco para fazer a sinalização da pergunta, por estar em inglês e recomendar a sua tradução, porém, a pergunta foi fechada nesse meio tempo. Ao tentar sinalizar, é exibido um hint(*em vermelho*), só que **em inglês**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pode sugerir uma tradução em: https://pt.traducir.win/string/5200

Comment: Opa. Vou dar uma olhada, não conhecia esse link.